# Issue with li's being hidden, button is too far down

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html "Load More" and "Load Less" code thingy. Basically it shows a few blocks and then you hit "Load More" and all of them show. Now I'm having an issue with how far down the button is. I want the button to be right below the first set of li's instead its like 300px below.

here's my jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/gmhfe2w7

index.html

```
<div class="load-more-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="load-more" />
  <ul>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
  </ul>
  <label class="load-more-btn" for="load-more">
                        <span class="unloaded"><p                                   class="button_more">
                        Load More
                        </p></span>
                        <span class="loaded"><p                                     class="button_less">
                        Load Less
                        </p></span>
                    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

loadmore.css

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.load-more-container {
  width: 959px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.load-more-container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.load-more-container ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.load-more-container ul li {
  width: 305px;
  background: #6d11d0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.load-more-container ul li:nth-child(1n + 4) {
  max-height: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.load-more-container .load-more-btn {
  text-align: center;
}
.load-more-container .load-more-btn .loaded {
  display: none;
}
.load-more-container #load-more {
  display: none;
}
.load-more-container #load-more:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(1n + 4) {
  max-height: 999px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}
.load-more-container #load-more:checked ~ .load-more-btn .loaded {
  display: block;
}
.load-more-container #load-more:checked ~ .load-more-btn .unloaded {
  display: none;
}
.load-more-container .ld{
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 380px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.load-more-container .uld{
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.margin{
  margin-top: 37px;
}
.button_more{
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 32px 16px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made the following changes for your CSS for check and uncheck input and check again. Let me know if you are still facing issues.

```
.load-more-container #load-more:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(1n + 4) {
    max-height: 999px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.load-more-container ul li:nth-child(1n + 4) {
    max-height: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to your CSS code:

```
.load-more-container #load-more:not(:checked) ~ ul li:nth-child(1n + 4) {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `opacity` CSS because it's not visible but it takes its element size in DOM. Try to use `display` property. Go through [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmhfe2w7/4/) to see live.

HTML Code -

```
<div class="load-more-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="load-more" />
  <ul>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li>Yeet</li>
    <li style="width: 305px; margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 22px;">Yeet</li>
  </ul>
  <label class="load-more-btn" for="load-more">
                        <span class="unloaded"><p                                   class="button_more">
                        Load More
                        </p></span>
                        <span class="loaded"><p                                     class="button_less">
                        Load Less
                        </p></span>
                    </label>
</div>
```

CSS Code -

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.load-more-container {
  width: 959px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.load-more-container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.load-more-container ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.load-more-container ul li {
  width: 305px;
  background: #6d11d0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.load-more-container ul li:nth-child(1n + 4) {
  max-height: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  display: none;
}

.load-more-container .load-more-btn {
  text-align: center;
}

.load-more-container .load-more-btn .loaded {
  display: none;
}

.load-more-container #load-more {
  display: none;
}

.load-more-container #load-more:checked~ul li:nth-child(1n + 4) {
  max-height: 999px;
  /* opacity: 1; */
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  display: block;
}

.load-more-container #load-more:checked~.load-more-btn .loaded {
  display: block;
}

.load-more-container #load-more:checked~.load-more-btn .unloaded {
  display: none;
}

.load-more-container .ld {
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 380px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.load-more-container .uld {
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.margin {
  margin-top: 37px;
}

.button_more, .button_less {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 32px 16px;
}
```